# JSON Limited to 1180 Characters

Tags: json, web-config, webmethod, svc

I have a simple JavaScript JSON request which stringify's an object to send via a JSON request to my C# Web server.

Whenever the string returned by stringy is over 1180 characters, the WebMethod is not called on the server.

From my understanding, there is no limit on how much string data the client can send via JSON.  I understand that the limitation is on the server end, trying to accept the paramaterized request.

Is there somewhere in the web.config that I can increase this limit of 1180?

My current config;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;initial catalog=aspnetdb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="ApplicationServices2" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;initial catalog=trimweb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="ApplicationServices3" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;initial catalog=Customers" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="ApplicationServices4" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;initial catalog=OrderUpdate;User ID=test1;Password=test1;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
            <webHttp />
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
          <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
        </webHttpBinding>

      </bindings>
      <services>
        <service name="ServiceSite.CustomersService">
          <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="ServiceSite.CustomersService"
                    behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"/>
        </service>
      </services>
    </system.serviceModel>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youll need to change your `webHttpBinding` to something like the below:

```
   <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"/>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="200000000" maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
   </webHttpBinding>
```

[See the docs for `<webHttpBinding>` here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412176(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Note:** Increasing this value alone is not sufficient in ASP.NET compatible mode. You should also increase the value of httpRuntime (see [httpRuntime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx)).

This should be something like:

```
<httpRuntime 
   maxQueryStringLength = "2048"
   maxRequestLength="4096"
   maxUrlLength = "260"
   requestLengthDiskThreshold="80"/>
```

**(Increase amounts as needed)**

Comment: Delighted, thank you very much for your continued support.

This did up my limit, but only to ~1250 :(

Comment: Delighted, I can not thank you enough. I am so very grateful for your help

Comment: Happy to have helped :)